# Generate a sfv file with bash (crcs along with the paths)

Tags: find, hashsum

How would I script something so that it gives me a list of crcs along with the paths, like an sfv file? I could code this in python but there is probably a simpler way in shell.

So far I have:

```
find . -type f -exec crc32 {} \; > chksum.txt
```

But this doesn't include the paths

An example output would be:

```
file_one.zip   c45ad668
file_two.zip   7903b8e6
file_three.zip e99a65fb
```

Comment: Is this the `crc32` utility distributed as part of the `Archive::Zip` Perl module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a sub-shell inside the `-exec` option that can go through the individual file names and do the action of your choice

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    for file; do 
        echo "$file" "$(crc32 "$file")"
    done' sh {} +
```

The for loop inside gets the list of names from `find` as one long list of positional arguments, i.e. `for file; do` is a short hand representation for `for file in "$@"; do` where the list `$@` is populated by `find` command.